# How do I show a fragment from an Android custom component?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've got a custom component declared using merge tags that is used in several locations in my application. Is it possible to call `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` from this class? This class extends the LinearLayout instead of an activity. What I'm trying to do is show a new fragment from this custom component, but neither of these functions can be accessed. How do I show the new fragment from this custom component?

Here are the basics of my code:

```
public class SpecialTextBox extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    //......constructors

    public void initialize(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_box, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        super.callOnClick();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.searchButton:
                SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment(new DialogFragmentDismissHandler(), specialBox.getEditText().getText().toString());
                searchFragment.show(dashboardActivity.getFragmentManager(), SearchFragment.class.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customAttribute="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <com.mobile.layout.SpecialEditText
                android:id="@+id/specialBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text=""
                style="@style/value"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                    style="@style/searchImageButton"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/myButton"
                    style="@style/reportButton"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                style="@style/value"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: Pass in a reference to an Activity maybe?

Comment: *How do I show the new fragment from this custom component?* - a `View` receives a `Context` reference in its constructor(available also through `getContext()`). Cast that reference to an Activity or ActionBarActivity if you plan to use support fragments and you're good to go.

Comment: When I try and cast getContext() to an activity, it says Cannot cast 'android.view.ContextThemeWrapper' to 'android.app.Activity'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access getFragmentManager() by the following:

```
Activity a = (Activity)(((ContextWrapper) getContext()).getBaseContext());
a.getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` only from FragmentActivity. If your custom view is inside `FragmentActivity`, you can this

```
FragmentActivity a = (FragmentActivity) getContext();
a.getFragmentManager()
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Cannot cast 'android.view.ContextThemeWrapper' to 'android.app.Activity'". But that got me started on the right idea...thanks for your help!